# How to enable retry on a 2nd-gen Firebase background function in Python?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to make my Python event-driven function retryable through code. However, I couldn't find the `failurePolicy` parameter they've described in the [Firebase official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries#configure_retries_from_your_function_code).